# Failing to get firestore information when using getStaticProps on Next.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, getstaticprops

I am trying to read data from firebase firestore and it keeps giving me the error

> TypeError: querySnapshot is not a function

Where could I be going wrong?. My code below is how I am writting it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { db } from '@/firebase';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

     
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'blogs'));
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().title);
    });
    
    return {
        props: {
            blogs: querySnapshot()
        }
    }
}

function index({blogs}) {
  return (
    <div>
        {blogs.map(blog => {
            <p>{blog.title}</p>
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default index
```

Comment: `querySnapshot` isn't a function you can call.  It's an object that contains all the documents.  You need to iterate it and build the data to display. I suggest reviewing again the documentation I linked you to in your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySnapshot` is an object and you are calling it as a function here:

```
   props: {
        blogs: querySnapshot()
    }
```

this is the proper way:

```
      let blogs = [];
      querySnaphot?.forEach((doc) => {
        blogs.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });
```

then you return:

```
   props: {
        blogs: blogs
    }
```

Comment: thanks bro it is now working. have a good day